# Invoking dependent microservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, microservices

Let's say that I have 2 microservices: Service1 and Service2. Each one of them has its own database. Service1 has EntityA and Service2 has EntityB

```
EntityA {
    Long id;
    //other fields
    EntityB entity;
}

EntityB{
     //other fields
}
```

I'm using Spring's RestTemplate for retrieving and saving data. The problem is : when retrieving EntityA from Service1's database I don't have data of EntityB as they are held in Service2's db, I understand that I should make a rest call via RestTemplate to retrieve EntityB from Service2's db, but what about relationship between the entities - should EntityA still have the whole EntityB object inside even though its fields are null most of the time except id ? What am I missing? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a technical perspective, your problem can be fixed via an [API Gateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html).

In a nutshell, you should define a new microservice, say `gateway service`, that will be called by your API clients. The `gateway service` would then:

1. Invoke `Service1` to get `Entity1` along with the `id` for `Entity2`
2. Invoke `Service2` to get `Entity2` based on the id from step 1.
3. Aggregate the two responses (in you case, setting the `Entity2` values inside `Entity1`).
4. Return the aggregated response to the client.

**Two thing to keep in mind while you design:**

- Your API client should not be aware his data is fetched by two services.
- It is generally cleaner to aggregate client response in the gateway, since it allows a higher level of decoupling between your microservices. For example, you could model your entities as follows (and remove the data model dependency between `Service1` and `Service2`, allowing the two services to evolve independently).

**See the below snippet:**

```
// In Service1
EntityA {
    Long bId; 
}

// In Service2
EntityB{

}

// In Gateway
Response {
    EntityA a;
    EntityB b;
}
```

The decision of weather `Entity1` should reference `Entity2` is not dependent on how your data is distributed but on your business needs. If you would have a monolithic application and in that context it would make sense for `Entity1` to reference `Entity2`, it still makes sense to do so in a microservice environment.

Comment: Thank you Alex, your answer helped me a lot. I am actually extracting part of monolithic application and making it a microservice. It's first of about 4 microservices to be extracted. Could you recommend some reading connected with this topic? I have one more question - what should I do when I have to make some decision in Service1 which impacts EntityA and is based on the data from EntityB ? Isn't it a sign of a bad design ?

Comment: @devoxy Ideally, the two microservices should evolve separately. That is rarely the case in practice though. A common approach is to integrate your microserives via queues. You could for example publish a message on data changes related to `EntityB` (from `Service2`) and consume those messages in `Service1` (where you would have some logic related to the data change from `Service2`). It's not necessarily a sign of a bad design, but you should asses weather you are mixing responsibilities or not. Did I answer your question though?

Comment: Regarding documentation, the API gateway pattern is properly described (from a theoretical perspective at least) in the link from my answer. The practical approach depends a lot on your technology stack, constraints, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex once again. When I wrote 'Could you recommend some reading connected with this topic?' I meant some examples of extracting microservice from monolith :). I know it's a very complex task but I couldn't find anything containing actual code samples, just advices about general steps to perform.

Comment: Sorry, nothing that specific comes to mind. I know there is a video in Spring IO with some hands on coding about refactoring a monolith to microservices, but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

The two solutions that come to my mind are both easy and complicated in the same time.

**Duplicate data**

In between of MS's, there's usually a highly available pub-sub or message queue clustered system. When the `EntityB` is saved in `Service2` you send an event into the queue or pub-sub system. `Service1` can subscribe to that particular event and store the information about `EntityB` in its own database.

**Group domain logic**

Maybe, there's just too big correlation between domain of `Service1` and `Service2`.
In that case, you might want to have your services grouped into a single service.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this pattern and I think it useful for your situation.
The pattern is called CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation, a mouthful)

The pattern assumes that you have an event sourcing system in place, which there is a high change you have since you are working with microservices.

When any **EntityA** from **Service1** is changed, **Service1** publishes an event. The same goes for **Service2**, when any **EntityB** si changed it will also publish an event.

Then we have **Service3** which subscribes to the events coming from **Service1** and **Service2** aggregates the data and stores it in its local database. Now all you have to do is call **Service3** to get the agregated data from **Service1** and **Service2**.

Of course this pattern comes with its downside like eventual consistency but it some scenarios it may actually be the best fit.

The idea comes mostly from here: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/cqrs.html.
I would also read at least the "when to use this pattern" section from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs